# how to get closest record from a table on a specific condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below.

```
Name            flag
--------------------------------
ABC             success
DEF             fail
GHI             success
JKL             fail
MNO             fail
PQR             fail
STU             fail
```

I have to get the record next below to the "success" flag record.I have tried couple of times but i am new to mysql.

my record hhould be like :-

```
Name            flag
--------------------------------
JKL             fail
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the record where flag=fail and record with id minus 1 and flag =success? Oh wait that's the query!

Comment: @StephaneM Thank u for the reply i have edited the question. Ignore the filed Id . Any other ideas to solve this issue

Comment: Define "next". There is no specified order by default in a table, you will have to define it.

Comment: Do you mean "the record with the next alfabetical value of column Name"?

Comment: @Roemer. Could you please make clear wat u meant for

Comment: There IS NO DEFAULT ORDER. So there is no default definition for "next". Except what YOU define. So define: what do you mean by "next/order". Alphabetical order of the field "Name"?

Comment: IF that is so, the solution is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name > (SELECT MIN(Name) FROM table WHERE flag='success') ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)I have considered the'id' column to consider the next record

```
  select * from yourtable where id = (select id from yourtable where flag='success')+1
```

or

2)I have also considered using rownum

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    (`Name` varchar(3), `flag` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
    (`Name`, `flag`)
VALUES
    ('ABC', 'fail'),
    ('DEF', 'fail'),
    ('GHI', 'success'),
    ('JKL', 'fail'),
    ('MNO', 'fail'),
    ('PQR', 'fail'),
    ('STU', 'fail')
;

create temporary  table t1 as 

select name,flag,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum
from yourtable ,(SELECT @rownum := 0) as r;

select name,flag from t1 where rownum = 
(select rownum from t1 where flag='success')+1
```

Check here-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbd4b/5

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Forget about the ID.Is there any Another way to fetch this ?

Comment: Not if you cannot tell us what the "next" record means. Define "next".

Comment: You can’t be sure that id+1 exists. It could be deleted and next should be id+2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table_1]
WHERE [Table_1].id > (SELECT [Table_1].id FROM [Table_1] WHERE flag = 'success')
LIMIT 1
```

Should return first row after flag "success"

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any another idea to solve this without using ID filed.

Comment: There can be problem if someone use sorting. ID field should be the best way. It defines the order in which records were added. You can add next column which contains date of adding record to database and then use it to define which records are newer than choosen one.

Comment: So you can also read something about getting rownumber from `select` query. Then use it to get value `rownum + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested to use windows functions.

select *,lead(flag, success) over (order by name) as next_comm
from yourtable;